# Bootstrap overflow scrolling tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any bootstrap extension that allows you to have more tabs than screen size can accomodate as in picture below where next button should make visible tabs number 5,6 etc. And is it possible to make this responsive as in picture 2??

[image: desktop]

[image: mobile]

Thanks a bunch!!! Hope it's all clear from the title, feel free to change ;)

P.S. Custom solution(jquery/css) is more than welcomed too :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://bootply.com/128029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2019)**

[Scrolling Tabs in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498596/scrolling-tabs-in-bootstrap4), or overflow to a dropdown: https://codeply.com/go/j2DdSGQg0s

**Bootstrap 3** (original answer)

Here is a horizontal scrolling tabs example for Bootstrap 3. You may need to tweak the style of the next/prev arrows accordingly..

http://bootply.com/128029

Comment: Its has one bug like if i activated last Tab then it is not moving to last active tab.