# Scrolling Tabs in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on scrolling tab. Below is my code. I am facing problem that I am not able to click middle tabs. On right button click tabs scrolls move it gradually. What should I do to move tabs gradually? Please help

```
var hidWidth;
var scrollBarWidths = 40;

var widthOfList = function() {
    var itemsWidth = 0;
    $('.list a').each(function() {
        var itemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        itemsWidth += itemWidth;
    });
    return itemsWidth;
};

var widthOfHidden = function() {
    return (($('.wrapper').outerWidth()) - widthOfList() - getLeftPosi()) - scrollBarWidths;
};

var getLeftPosi = function() {
    return $('.list').position().left;
};

var reAdjust = function() {
    if (($('.wrapper').outerWidth()) < widthOfList()) {
        $('.scroller-right').show().css('display', 'flex');
    } else {
        $('.scroller-right').hide();
    }

    if (getLeftPosi() < 0) {
        $('.scroller-left').show().css('display', 'flex');
    } else {
        $('.item').animate({
            left: "-=" + getLeftPosi() + "px"
        }, 'slow');
        $('.scroller-left').hide();
    }
}

reAdjust();

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    reAdjust();
});

$('.scroller-right').click(function() {

    $('.scroller-left').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.scroller-right').fadeOut('slow');

    $('.list').animate({
        left: "+=" + widthOfHidden() + "px"
    }, 'slow', function() {

    });
});

$('.scroller-left').click(function() {

    $('.scroller-right').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.scroller-left').fadeOut('slow');

    $('.list').animate({
        left: "-=" + getLeftPosi() + "px"
    }, 'slow', function() {

    });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/2uswn4od/13

Help me to scroll slowly on button click so that I can click on ease tab. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? it is quite confusing to understand from what you wrote.

Comment: When I click on right button to scroll tabs it scrolls to end thats why I am not able to click tabs which are placed in middle

Comment: I am able to click tab 8 without any issue

Comment: check resizing window you will understand my problem. Please minimize screen and check

Comment: You should move it gradually by 50px and it should work.

Comment: can you please help me with this

Comment: Check this out https://codepen.io/srees/pen/pgVLbm

Comment: no same poroblem in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should incrementally move the tabs "width of hidden", but no more than wrapper width...

```
var widthOfHidden = function(){

    var ww = 0 - $('.wrapper').outerWidth();
    var hw = (($('.wrapper').outerWidth())-widthOfList()-getLeftPosi())-scrollBarWidths;

    if (ww>hw) {
        return ww;
    }
    else {
        return hw;
    }

};

var getLeftPosi = function(){

    var ww = 0 - $('.wrapper').outerWidth();
    var lp = $('.list').position().left;

    if (ww>lp) {
        return ww;
    }
    else {
        return lp;
    }
};
```

And then "readjust" after each movement to determine whether or not the scroll arrows still need to show...

```
$('.scroller-right').click(function() {

  $('.scroller-left').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.scroller-right').fadeOut('slow');

  $('.list').animate({left:"+="+widthOfHidden()+"px"},'slow',function(){
    reAdjust();
  });
});

$('.scroller-left').click(function() {

    $('.scroller-right').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.scroller-left').fadeOut('slow');

    $('.list').animate({left:"-="+getLeftPosi()+"px"},'slow',function(){
        reAdjust();
    });
});
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/Loo3CqsA7T

---

Also, you can improve the position of the last tab by making sure it's right position is never less than wrapper width to keep it aligned to the right edge...

```
var widthOfHidden = function(){

    var ww = 0 - $('.wrapper').outerWidth();
    var hw = (($('.wrapper').outerWidth())-widthOfList()-getLeftPosi())-scrollBarWidths;
    var rp = $(document).width() - ($('.nav-item.nav-link').last().offset().left + $('.nav-item.nav-link').last().outerWidth());

    if (ww>hw) {
        return (rp>ww?rp:ww);
    }
    else {
        return (rp>hw?rp:hw);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @Zim. I have implemented your code working fine but facing one problem when I continuosly click on left right buttons then tablist going away from area. Sometimes it not working normally. can you please help with this

Answer (score -1):

https://embed.plnkr.co/NcdGqX/

Look at this example. this tabs move gradually. and also you can use bootstrap 4.

I hope it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Uday but I want to do this without any plugin.Thank you